# How does Kenneth French create the industry portfolio returns?

Tags: equities, portfolio-management, fama-french

Kenneth Frenches Data Library includes industry portfolios.

Is this done via a software of some type.

I have some stock returns but I want to calculcated the returns of the industries in the Chinese market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constitution of each industry portfolio is described in each "detail"-section on [Kenneth French´s homepage](http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html). The industries are defined by sorting each NYSE, AMEX, and NASDAQ stock based on its four digit [SIC-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Industrial_Classification).

The sort is applied at the end of June of year $t$. Monthly returns are calculated for the subsequent year, i.e. from July of year $t$ to end of June in year $t+1$. The portfolio return is the average [value-weighted return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization-weighted_index) of each stock, i.e. you weight each stock return with its market-valuation (number of shares outstanding times stock price). The procedure is clearly described in the below reference.

---

#### Reference

[Fama/French (1997)](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-405X(96)00896-3), *Industry Cost of Equity*, Journal of Financial Economics (43).

Comment: I've see your point, but in terms of the finer details,

Comment: So in June are the weights create and then not rebalanced until next june, Therefore, to give a simple example with two stocks, A and B, if we start in June with 50% in each and the return in July is 30% for stock A and 0% for stock B, the weights will actually be 56.5% for stock A and 43.5% for Stock B. The portfolios are only rebalanced each June.

Comment: What you describe is an equal-weighted portfolio return. You have to multiply the return of july (e.g. 30% for stock $A$) with the equivalent market-valuation at the end of june (number of shares outstanding times stock price of $A$ at the end of june) and divide both by the total market capitalization of all stocks within this portfolio. This results in a value-weighted portfolio return where each stock weight keeps track with price changes.

Comment: Thats what I am after! Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Would you happen to know how to handle missing data?

Comment: I've assumed that I can drop any companies that have any missing data for the year ahead but I suppose this is forward looking what an actual investor wouldnt have the benefit of.

Comment: If there is data missing at the end of june, you don't consider this stock for the sort in end of june until data is available (e.g. a company gets listed in august, it is disregarded until june of the subsequent year, even if you have data from august till june). On the other hand, if a stock gets delisted, you consider it until delisting, but be aware of the [delisting bias](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2329566) for the return of the month of the delisting. If there is missing data for just one month, simply skip that month for return calculation.

Comment: What if there is missing data in say January!

Comment: Do I act like the return was 0

Comment: No, you just have to ignore this (single) missing return for your calculations and consider this stock as soon as data is available again.

Comment: When you say ignore. Say ive got two stocks, A and B, both starting with a weight of 50%, in month 1, the return of A is 10% and the Return of B is -10%, in the next month the weights 55% and 45% for A and B respectively. however, the return of A is 10% and the return of B is missing. So in month two will I display the return of my portfolio as 10% or 5.5%?

Comment: My question remains!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84946/discussion-between-skoestlmeier-and-zarina-akhtar).